# Undefined variable in php but is defined?

Tags: php, sql, variables

I want to do a profile page leading from the main page, and when I signed in and click on profile page, I have this 2 error. I want to show the first name and last name.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: first_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\FontLibrary\Profile.php on line 181
```

and

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: last_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\FontLibrary\Profile.php on line 183
```

But I already defined it at the if statement?

The relevant code is

```
<?php
            session_start();
            include 'dbfunctions.php';
            $msg = "";
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            if (!isset($id)) {
                $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            }

            // Build the SELECT statement
            $select_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ".$id;

            //Run the Query
            $result = mysql_query($select_query);

            if ($result) {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $first_name = $row['first_name'];
                $last_name = $row['last_name'];
            }
            ?>
```

and

```
    First Name:<?php echo $first_name ?> <br />
    Last Name:<?php echo $last_name ?> <br />
```

Comment: What if the `if` condition evaluates to `false`?

Comment: Are these two snippets even on the same page? Do you actually get a `$result`?

Comment: Yes they are on the same page.

Answer (score 4):

`var_dump()` your `$result` to check it contains what you expect.

Chances are your query failed (or returned nothing) so `$first_name` and `$last_name` were never set as it will have skipped over the if statement.

And/Or you could initialise them before the if statement.

```
$first_name = "";
$last_name = "";
if ($result) 
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    $last_name = $row['last_name'];
}
```

As a side note, `mysql_` functions have been deprecated. Please consider using [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: If that is the entire script, then I don't see any connection code to the database? If that's just omitted then when `result` is false you can try `echo mysql_error();` to see what the error was.

Comment: Thanks! I found out the reason already. Because I didn't add $link when I run the query.

Answer (score 0):

If your result is false, than variables are not deffined. You have to define them also outdide if block with default values.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your call to `mysql_query()` doesn't return a value.

`if ($result)` is false.

Also please, please please escape strings you pass to the DB!!! :(